# Window and noverlap values in pwelch function of Matlab

Tags: eeg, signal-processing

Could anyone please suggest what values to be used for Window and noverlap inputs of pwelch function in Matlab. I am using a 200 ms EEG signal with sampling frequency 1000 (so total samples 200) to evaluate spectral power. By default pwelch uses hamming window and divides the data into 8 segments with 50% overlap. Are these default values okay for my small signal?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. Could you perhaps provide a little more context about your study. What are you studying, and how will you analyze the data after applying the window?

Comment: This is a study of ERP response to stimuli in a 200 ms time duration. I want to compare the spectral powers in different frequency bands.